# Excel with negative numbers

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to put in a number as a total, say B2. Then put in a negative number under it in B3, and subtract B3 form B2 and B2 shows the total. If i put in 10 in B2 and -5 in B3 and then B2 would show 5.

Comment: This is not a programming question and would be better served at a different stack exchange site: superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an example of circular reference and therefore not possible.  The result of the calling cell depends on the value of the referenced cell which depends on the value of the calling cell.  It can never come to a resolution.

You can instead do one of two options.  Change B2 into a formula:

=10+B3

This way B2 will show the value 5 by adding the negative -5 from B3 to 10.

Else, if you need it to be more dynamic, then add the 10 value to some other cell.  For instance:

B1: 10, B2: =B1+B3, B3: -5

With the above B2 will show the value 5.  You can then later change the B1 and/or B3 values to manipulate B2.  For instance, if you change B1 to 5, and B3 remains the same, then B2 will show 0.